# Securely copy files to a UNC path using .NET

Tags: security, encryption, .net, file-copying

I need to copy files from one server to a UNC path on the same network. The ASP.NET app uses .NET 2.0

Currently we're just using a simple System.IO.File.Copy method, and works just fine, but we were asked to make sure the files are transferred securely.

I can think of two ways to do this. Either writing a WCF or ASMX service and install a SSL certificate on the target server, and use that, or, explicitly encrypting each file before calling File.Copy, and then decrypting the file once it's copied.

Am I missing an option? Are there better ways to do this? If not...which option would be best for my requirement?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement to "make sure the files are transferred securely".  You're saying you want the data transmission (on the wire) encrypted so that it cannot be "sniffed"?  If that's the case, encrypting the file on the source, copying, and decrypting on the destination is not going to do that (unless the decryption happens _on_ the destination).

Comment: Hence the WCF/ASMX service, I suppose...

Comment: Yeah, what does 'securely' mean?

Comment: I can't really paste the requirements, but it talks about 128bit encryption (i'm guessing for the channel?) and strong authentication.

Comment: wanted to clarify my concern and the reason for the question. We're copying files using the IO File.Copy method, and I was concern that anybody in our network could just open a network sniffer and be able to sniff the stream and transform that back to the file that we're transferring. I did a more specific question on superuser.com, and apparently it's not a trivial task (not just launching a program and seeing all files being transferred over the network) so I guess I am good for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial concern was that a person in my LAN could just launch a simple tool and get a copy of the files being copied between servers on my LAN.

After asking a related question on superuser.com - [can a file being copied over my LAN be sniffed?](https://superuser.com/questions/347500/can-a-file-being-copied-over-my-lan-be-sniffed), i learned that even if a regular person is able to launch a popular sniffer tool like WireShark and configure it to see the stream of the files being copied over the network, it would not be an easy task to convert that stream back into a file. It would take a higher skill to do that.

However, for safety, I'd go with encrypting the stream (WCF or ASMX service over SSL) so that even if they can see the stream, it'd still be encrypted.